# Return error message if username exists with Django and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I created my first Django app and have begun restyling it. I was using the standard {% load bootstrap3 %} but in the style I am switching to Bootstrap 4. I am using Django's UserCreationForm. I restyled the landing page and the signup form.

Here is the HTML of the form.

```
            <form method="post" id="signUpForm" action="{% url 'users:register' %}" class="form">
               {% csrf_token %}
                <!-- Username and Email -->
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm">
                        <input type="text" name="username" minlength="2" maxlength="100" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                        <!-- <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken.</div> -->
                        <small class="form-text text-muted">Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        <!-- <div class="form-control-feedback">Please enter a valid email.</div> -->
                        <small class="form-text text-muted">youremail@example.com</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Password -->
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm form-group">
                           <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-danger form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" required>
                           <small class="form-text text-muted">At least 8 characters.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" class="form-control form-control-danger form-control-lg" id="inputHorizontalDanger" placeholder="Password confirmation" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Submit Button -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn-landing btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info">Create Free Account</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I am using https://jqueryvalidation.org/ to dynamically validate the form input.

But I need to check if the username already exists and alert the user.

Is there a way to check the username before submitting?

I understand how to check the minlength, etc with jQuery but I am unsure about the Django side of it since I'm new to it.

Comment: as usual AJAX is your friend. Send a request with the username query check if the name exists and send an answer back. Find a Ajax tutorial and work your way up ;)

Comment: Thanks @hansTheFranz. I haven't used AJAX much so I didn't think to look there. Thanks for getting me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Armed with AJAX as a search property I came across this example.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Anyone else searching a similar question this should give you what you need to figure it out.